# Appended string from iframe being duplicated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a basic `iframe` based upload script but I have a problem when it comes to outputting the success message. After each file is uploaded the success message should be appended just once once but for each file uploaded it is appended +1 times (1,2,3, times etc).

Here's the query file (*uploader.js*):

```
$(function(){
    $('#uploader .upload_submit').click(function(){
        $('#uploader .upload_iframe').load(function(){
            var JSONResponse = $.parseJSON($(this.contentDocument).text());

            if (JSONResponse.error == true)
            {
                $('#uploader .upload_errors').text('An error occured: '+JSONResponse.error_message)
                    .hide()
                    .slideDown();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#uploader .upload_errors').fadeOut();
                // problem occurs here (should only append once)
                $('#uploader .upload_messages').append('upload success');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and *html* file:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="uploader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="uploader">
    <iframe src="upload.php" name="upload_iframe" class="upload_iframe"></iframe>
    <div class="upload_messages"></div>
    <div class="upload_errors"></div>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" target="upload_iframe" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="userfile" value="" id="userfile" class="upload_field"  />
        <input type="submit" name="upload_submit" value="Submit" class="upload_submit" />
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and sample **JSON** output from *upload.php* (on success):

```
{"error":false,"error_message":"","success_data":{"message":"File uploaded successfully","origonal_filename":"egg.jpg"}}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing line 3:

```
$('#uploader .upload_iframe').load(function(){
```

to this:

```
$('#uploader .upload_iframe').one('load', function(){
```